# Opendaylight integration with IDP/LDAP for authn/authz

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

Is it possible to integrate Opendaylight(AAA) with IDP (or) LDAP for authn/authz ? Or is this part of ODL future roadmap ?

I could see some reference [documents](http://docs.inocybe.com/dev-guide/content/_how_federated_authentication_is_set_up.html) stating about the above ones.
Does anyone tried it, if so could you please share me the steps/configuration details.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit this file {KARAF_HOME}/etc/shiro.ini

ODL provides a few LDAP implementations that are disabled out of the box. ODLJndiLdapRealm includes authorization functionality based on LDAP elements that are extracted through an LDAP search. This requires a bit of knowledge about how your LDAP system is setup.

```
ldapRealm = org.opendaylight.aaa.shiro.realm.ODLJndiLdapRealm
ldapRealm.userDnTemplate = uid={0},ou=<PEOPLE>,dc=<DOMAIN>,dc=<TLD>
ldapRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://<URL>:<PORT>
ldapRealm.searchBase = dc=<DOMAIN>,dc=<TLD>
ldapRealm.ldapAttributeForComparison = <OBJECTCLASS>
...
```

Stacked realm configuration; realms are round-robbined until authentication succeeds or realm sources are exhausted. 
The $ldapRealm is only required if you are enabling LDAP. securityManager.realms = $tokenAuthRealm, $ldapRealm

Comment: Thanks Icaro. I will look into it.